# Prometheus query to count unique labels over a timeframe

Tags: prometheus, promql

I need to count the number of unique labelsets for a prometheus metric over a given timeframe. For example, "How many unique labelsets have a value of 1 at some point during the past 7 days."

I've investigated using `count` and `count_over_time` but `count` only operates on instant vectors meaning I can get the number of unique labelsets for an instance in time, but not in aggregate over a timeframe. `count_over_time` returns the number of values which isn't useful since I need to know the number of labelsets and not how many values each has.

Basically I want something like `count((metric_name >= 1)[7d])`. This is a very easy problem to solve outside of PromQL by just making the range query `metric_name >= 1` over 7 days and then counting the number of series in the result field of the response, but I want to perform this query in PromQL if possible.

Answer (score 14):

Figured it out. `count(count_over_time(metric[range]))` gives the value I want.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the interval between samples (aka `scrape_interval` in Prometheus ecosystem), then the following query should return the number of unique labelsets (aka `unique time series` - see [this article](https://valyala.medium.com/prometheus-storage-technical-terms-for-humans-4ab4de6c3d48) for more details about commonly used technical terms in Prometheus) with values `>=1` over the last 7 days if `scrape_interval=30s`:

```
count(count_over_time((metric >= 1)[7d:30s])
```

This query uses [subquery feature](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/) from PromQL.

If `scrape_interval` is unknown beforehand, then the task cannot be solved with PromQL. But it can be solved with [count_gt_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#count_gt_over_time) and [count_eq_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#count_eq_over_time) functions in [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html):

```
count(count_gt_over_time(metric[7d], 1) or count_eq_over_time(metric[7d], 1))
```